# User Access to Accounts and Opportunities/ Sharing Rule on Formula field work around

Tags: userrecordaccess, sharing-rule

I have a picklist field(Team__c) at User level with different Team Names in it, which is pulled on to Accounts and Opportunities using a formula field.

So now I need to give access to a user to edit any accounts or opportunities owned by different user if the Team__c equals "Team A".

So I tried to do this using Sharing rules but in the criteria I'm not able to access the formula field to check for the team__c. **FYI** - In the roles he has edit access to all the records.

How can I achieve this ? I need to give him access to all the records owned by his Team.

Comment: Hove you looked into the Account Team feature of Salesforce? Maybe it will be able to be implemented and get you what you need

Comment: I'm not aware of the Account Team will look at it. But currently I fixed this in the long way by using WFs and mass update the old records to a new picklist field. Thank you.